# discord.py matching ranking role even if user doesn't have that role

Tags: discord.py

I am programming my level system and I have noticed a problem.
Since I want to do the ranking role (i.e. roles that are obtained by ranking) I made this script:

```py
async def role_up_by_xp_comand(cursor, check_level, user):
    if check_level == 1:
        recluta = get(user.guild.roles, id=690962671847342171)
        ambientato = get(user.guild.roles, id=690962461255270440)
        presente = get(user.guild.roles, id=690962769511710811)
        attivo = get(user.guild.roles, id=690962456897650755)
        rilevante = get(user.guild.roles, id=690962450211799070)
        veterano = get(user.guild.roles, id=690962271962267758)
        booster = get(user.guild.roles, id=726498072581898250)
        storico = get(user.guild.roles, id=690967861404893234)
        print(recluta, ambientato, presente, attivo, rilevante, veterano, booster, storico)
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT user_level FROM users WHERE client_id = {str(user.id)}")
        level = cursor.fetchall()
        lvl_user = level[0][0]
        print(str(lvl_user))
        if storico or booster:
            print(f"{user.name} ha un ruolo attività fisso quindi non non posso aumentargli il ruolo")
            return
        if 5 >= lvl_user <= 9:
            await user.remove_roles(recluta)
            await user.add_roles(ambientato)
            print(f"{user.name} è ufficialmente ambientato")
        elif 10 >= lvl_user <= 14:
            print("Ci sei arrivato")
            if recluta:
                print("Ci sei arrivato 2 volte")
                await user.remove_roles(recluta)
                await user.add_roles(presente)
                print(f"{user.name} è ufficialmente presente")
            elif ambientato:
                print("Ci sei arrivato 2 volte x2")
                print(user, ambientato, presente)
                await user.remove_roles(ambientato)
                await user.add_roles(presente)
                print(f"{user.name} è ufficialmente presente")
        elif 15 >= lvl_user <= 19:
            if recluta:
                await user.remove_roles(recluta)
                await user.add_roles(attivo)
                print(f"{user.name} è ufficialmente attivo")
            elif ambientato:
                await user.remove_roles(ambientato)
                await user.add_roles(attivo)
                print(f"{user.name} è ufficialmente attivo")
            elif presente:
                await user.remove_roles(presente)
                await user.add_roles(attivo)
                print(f"{user.name} è ufficialmente attivo")
        elif 20 >= lvl_user <= 24:
            if recluta:
                await user.remove_roles(recluta)
                await user.add_roles(rilevante)
                print(f"{user.name} è ufficialmente attivo")
            elif ambientato:
                await user.remove_roles(ambientato)
                await user.add_roles(attivo)
                print(f"{user.name} è ufficialmente attivo")
            elif presente:
                await user.remove_roles(presente)
                await user.add_roles(rilevante)
                print(f"{user.name} è ufficialmente attivo")
            elif attivo:
                await user.remove_roles(attivo)
                await user.add_roles(rilevante)
                print(f"{user.name} è ufficialmente rilevante")
        elif 25 >= lvl_user:
            if recluta:
                await user.remove_roles(recluta)
                await user.add_roles(veterano)
                print(f"{user.name} è ufficialmente veterano")
            elif ambientato:
                await user.remove_roles(ambientato)
                await user.add_roles(veterano)
                print(f"{user.name} è ufficialmente veterano")
            elif presente:
                await user.remove_roles(presente)
                await user.add_roles(veterano)
                print(f"{user.name} è ufficialmente veterano")
            elif attivo:
                await user.remove_roles(attivo)
                await user.add_roles(veterano)
                print(f"{user.name} è ufficialmente veterano")
            elif rilevante:
                await user.remove_roles(rilevante)
                await user.add_roles(veterano)
                print(f"{user.name} è ufficialmente veterano")
```

The problem is that despite having set the roles correctly (`user` comes from `discord.Member`) as soon as he sees the first `if` (`if storico or booster:`) even if the user does not have those two roles he accepts the condition. Sometimes it gives me the roles like `None` even if they are set correctly and sometimes it gives them correct but still they don't work. I don't understand what's going on I send the complete script:

```py
@client.command()
async def xp(ctx, xp: int, member: discord.Member=None):
    embed = discord.Embed(
        color=0xa61022
    )
    if not xp:
        embed.set_author(
            name="Per favore specifica quanto xp deve ricevere l'utente!",
        )
        await ctx.send(embed=embed, delete_after=10.0)
        return
    if not member:
        embed.set_author(
            name="Per favore specifica l'utente!",
        )
        await ctx.send(embed=embed, delete_after=10.0)
        return
    if member.bot:
        embed.set_author(
            name="Non puoi dare xp ai bot!",
        )
        await ctx.send(embed=embed, delete_after=10.0)
        return
    cursor = levelsystem_db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT user_xp FROM users WHERE client_id = {str(member.id)}")
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    print(result)
    print(len(result))
    if (len(result) == 0):
        print("L'utente non è stato aggiunto al database.")
        cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES({str(member.id)} ,{str(xp)} , 0)")
        levelsystem_db.commit()
        print("Aggiunta completata")
        print(f"{member.name} ha ricevuto {str(xp)} xp")
        check_level = await level_up(cursor, xp, member)
        print(check_level)
        await role_up_by_xp_comand(cursor, check_level, member)
    else:
        newXP = result[0][0] + xp
        print(f"Gli xp di {member.name} sono aggiornati a {newXP}")
        cursor.execute(f"UPDATE users SET user_xp = {str(newXP)} WHERE client_id = {str(member.id)}")
        levelsystem_db.commit()
        print(f"Aggiornamento degli xs di {member.name} completato.")
        check_level = await level_up(cursor, newXP, member)
        print(check_level)
        await role_up_by_xp_comand(cursor, check_level, member)
    embed = discord.Embed(
        color=0x03c03c
    )
    embed.set_author(
        name=f'Ho dato {xp}xp a {member.name}',
    )
    await ctx.send(embed=embed, delete_after=10.0)

async def level_up(cursor, NewXP, user):
    channel = client.get_channel(640563710104043530)
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT user_level FROM users WHERE client_id = {str(user.id)}")
    level = cursor.fetchall()
    lvl_start = level[0][0]
    lvl_end = int(NewXP ** (1/4))
    print(str(lvl_start), str(lvl_end))
    if (str(lvl_end) < str(lvl_start)) or (str(lvl_start) < str(lvl_end)):
        await channel.send(f"{user.mention} è salito al livello {lvl_end}")
        print(f"Il livello di {user.name} si sta aggiornando al livello {lvl_end}")
        cursor.execute(f"UPDATE users SET user_level = {str(lvl_end)} WHERE client_id = {str(user.id)}")
        levelsystem_db.commit()
        print(f"Aggiornamento del livello di {user.name} completato.")
        check_level = 1
        return check_level
    else:
        print("Non è abbastanza!")
        check_level = 0
        return check_level

async def role_up_by_xp_comand(cursor, check_level, user):
    if check_level == 1:
        recluta = get(user.guild.roles, id=690962671847342171)
        ambientato = get(user.guild.roles, id=690962461255270440)
        presente = get(user.guild.roles, id=690962769511710811)
        attivo = get(user.guild.roles, id=690962456897650755)
        rilevante = get(user.guild.roles, id=690962450211799070)
        veterano = get(user.guild.roles, id=690962271962267758)
        booster = get(user.guild.roles, id=726498072581898250)
        storico = get(user.guild.roles, id=690967861404893234)
        print(recluta, ambientato, presente, attivo, rilevante, veterano, booster, storico)
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT user_level FROM users WHERE client_id = {str(user.id)}")
        level = cursor.fetchall()
        lvl_user = level[0][0]
        print(str(lvl_user))
        if storico or booster:
            print(f"{user.name} ha un ruolo attività fisso quindi non non posso aumentargli il ruolo")
            return
        if 5 >= lvl_user <= 9:
            await user.remove_roles(recluta)
            await user.add_roles(ambientato)
            print(f"{user.name} è ufficialmente ambientato")
        elif 10 >= lvl_user <= 14:
            print("Ci sei arrivato")
            if recluta:
                print("Ci sei arrivato 2 volte")
                await user.remove_roles(recluta)
                await user.add_roles(presente)
                print(f"{user.name} è ufficialmente presente")
            elif ambientato:
                print("Ci sei arrivato 2 volte x2")
                print(user, ambientato, presente)
                await user.remove_roles(ambientato)
                await user.add_roles(presente)
                print(f"{user.name} è ufficialmente presente")
        elif 15 >= lvl_user <= 19:
            if recluta:
                await user.remove_roles(recluta)
                await user.add_roles(attivo)
                print(f"{user.name} è ufficialmente attivo")
            elif ambientato:
                await user.remove_roles(ambientato)
                await user.add_roles(attivo)
                print(f"{user.name} è ufficialmente attivo")
            elif presente:
                await user.remove_roles(presente)
                await user.add_roles(attivo)
                print(f"{user.name} è ufficialmente attivo")
        elif 20 >= lvl_user <= 24:
            if recluta:
                await user.remove_roles(recluta)
                await user.add_roles(rilevante)
                print(f"{user.name} è ufficialmente attivo")
            elif ambientato:
                await user.remove_roles(ambientato)
                await user.add_roles(attivo)
                print(f"{user.name} è ufficialmente attivo")
            elif presente:
                await user.remove_roles(presente)
                await user.add_roles(rilevante)
                print(f"{user.name} è ufficialmente attivo")
            elif attivo:
                await user.remove_roles(attivo)
                await user.add_roles(rilevante)
                print(f"{user.name} è ufficialmente rilevante")
        elif 25 >= lvl_user:
            if recluta:
                await user.remove_roles(recluta)
                await user.add_roles(veterano)
                print(f"{user.name} è ufficialmente veterano")
            elif ambientato:
                await user.remove_roles(ambientato)
                await user.add_roles(veterano)
                print(f"{user.name} è ufficialmente veterano")
            elif presente:
                await user.remove_roles(presente)
                await user.add_roles(veterano)
                print(f"{user.name} è ufficialmente veterano")
            elif attivo:
                await user.remove_roles(attivo)
                await user.add_roles(veterano)
                print(f"{user.name} è ufficialmente veterano")
            elif rilevante:
                await user.remove_roles(rilevante)
                await user.add_roles(veterano)
                print(f"{user.name} è ufficialmente veterano")
```

Comment: "How do I solve my problem with X" is not a very good title: it doesn't describe what the question is, and practically is a black box. Could you come up with a more compelling title?

Comment: I tried but I couldn't. Suggest me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're **not** checking if a user has that role, you're checking if the guild knows that role.

```
booster = get(user.guild.roles, id=726498072581898250)
storico = get(user.guild.roles, id=690967861404893234)
```

The above will retrieve a role with that id from the guild, NOT the user.
If those roles exist, then they will be returned. Since `if storico or booster:` checks if either of those are not null, this statement will always be true unless those roles don't exist on the server.

To check the actual user's roles, you need to access the `roles` property, described here: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#Member

I don't have an IDE at hand, but checking if a member has that role probably would be something like:

```
booster = get(user.roles, id=726498072581898250)
```